# How to find the current URL in Iron?

Tags: rust, iron

How can I find the current URL inside an action/function? I've not found anything related to this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The [Iron homepage](http://ironframework.io/) has this "hello world" example:

```
fn hello_world(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, "Hello World!")))
}
```

The only input to the function is a [`Request`](https://docs.rs/iron/0.5.1/iron/request/struct.Request.html). The very first field on that struct is a `Url`:

> `url`: `Url`
>
> The requested URL.